# Return alive Hosts with aynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I'm trying to retrieve a list of alive hosts via Javascript. The function for that matter should be implemented like the following:

```
//getState returns an array of states (up or down) for all the given list of ip addresses
var host_states = getState(list_of_ip_addresses);
```

In order to check if a host is alive or not, I'm using websockets:

```
var ip = "ws://"+current_ip;
var s = new WebSocket(ip);
//if the onerror is called, state host as up
s.onerror= function(){/*state host as up*/};
//after a delay, automatically state host as down
setTimeout(function(){/*state host as down*/},delay);
```

Since the the state of the host is determined via callbacks (asynchronous), how do I return the state of one or many hosts, like in the function above? (Without polling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Promises to return all of the host asynchronously at once.

```js
async function getStates(l) {
  let promises = [];
  for(let i in l) {
    let current_ip = l[i];
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let delay = 10;
      var ip = "ws://"+current_ip;
      var s = new WebSocket(ip);
      //if the onerror is called, state host as up
      s.onerror= function(){/*state host as up*/resolve(true)};
      //after a delay, automatically state host as down
      setTimeout(function(){/*state host as down*/resolve(false)},delay);
      
     }));
  };
  console.log(promises);
  const results = await Promise.all(promises);
  return results;
}
getStates([1,2,3]).then(r => console.log(r));
```

Comment: Don't do `results[i] = state;`. Just make `const results = await Promise.all(promises)`